# Update-Database failed for a Private nuget package gallery

Tags: nuget, nugetgallery

I'm trying to setup a local nuget gallery. While trying to create the DB manually (it doesn't support creating a database on the fly anymore) via Package Manager Console, I get the following error. Any ideas?

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_CuratedFeed_PackageRegistration' already exists on table 'CuratedPackages'.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable1 migrationStatements)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable1 migrationStatements)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable1 operations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
ClientConnectionId:c4c6b7b3-c7e8-4d8b-802a-7433badcdcb8
The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_CuratedFeed_PackageRegistration' already exists on table 'CuratedPackages'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually was a bug and has been resolved now. Check this - [Update-Database failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_CuratedFeed_PackageRegistration' already exists on table 'CuratedPackages'.](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/1204)